# Sharing a document in sharepoint 2013 on premise

Tags: document-library, external-users

I used to work with office365 but i now work on a pure sharepoint 2013 on premise environment. Things are quite different. So now i'm looking into ways to share a document from a document library with

- groups (pure internals)
- externals (not known to sharepoint and any directory service).
- contacts  (who already live in a trusted lightweight directory service)
- group of mixed contacts with internals.

*the contacts are derived from a different app and to sharepoint they are trusted users.

Ideally i would like to right click a document and share it to a specific user.
or else Email it to a user (popup fill in email address) 
But i dont want:

- share an entire document library, or an entire site.

I wonder how to achieve it.
Currently i'm thinking of maybe adding a workflow, so people could type an email addres, or type a distributionlist / group.

But then i need a button per document library list row to be able to send it.
Or some popup construction. Are there recommended ways to do this ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For external users, you may want to look into ACS, which you can configure to use Microsoft Accounts, Facebook, and a few others. An example reference can be found at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meacoex/2013/12/25/authenticate-your-sharepoint-website-users-with-facebook/. This in and of itself is a deep topic you will want to do research on.

For groups, you can simply add the users to an Active Directory Security Group and apply permission to SharePoint as appropriate using the People Picker to find the group.

For users who reside in LDAP (e.g. AD LDS), you can use Forms-based Authentication, or potentially SAML if your SAML provider can federate with your LDAP implementation. For an FBA configuration with specifically AD LDS, though easily adaptable to other LDAP systems, see https://thesharepointfarm.com/sharepoint-and-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services/.

Note that objects from Active Directory need a SID in order to be added to SharePoint security objects, therefor you cannot use Contacts or Distribution Groups in SharePoint for security purposes.

As these are quite in depth topics, if you're having issues with any specific one during implementation, I'd recommend creating individual questions here for them. This is why I've provided you with general links instead of specific step-by-step guidance.

Comment: Hm i've been thinking in this direction, there is one thing though that i kinda miss from office 365, and thats the easy sharing options; 
i would like to be able to share/mail by some method from the sharepoint GUI. So for example someone using a PDA or tablet can send a document easily to someone.

Comment: Understood, but that just doesn't exist outside of custom solutions.

Comment: by custom you mean a plugin, or a workflow

Comment: Full trust solution.